# 400 Error in Terraform code when trying to loop a widget field multiple times

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

```
I have the following code which I am trying to implement for multiple widgets in a single cloud watch dashboard

`    locals {
      instances = csvdecode(file("${path.module}/sample.csv"))
    }

    resource "aws_cloudwatch_dashboard" "main" {
      dashboard_name = "my-dashboard"

      dashboard_body = jsonencode(
     {
       "widgets": [
    for inst in range(length(local.instances)):[  
// i want to repeat the below section as the length of instances variable but getting an error  
           {   
              "type":"metric",
              "x":0,
              "y":0,
              "width":12,
              "height":6, 

              "properties":{

                 "metrics":[ // trying to implement multiple widget in a single dashboard 
    enter code here
                    [
                       "AWS/EC2",
                       "CPUUtilization",
                       "InstanceId",
                       "${local.instances[inst].instance_id}"
                    ]
                 ],
                 "period":300,
                 "stat":"Average",
                 "region":"ap-south-1",
                 "title":"EC2 Instance CPU",
                 "annotations": {
                    "horizontal": [
                          {
                             "label": "Untitled annotation",
                             "value": 1.01
                         }]
                       }          }
           }
      ]]
     })
    }   `
```

I am getting this error below error:

Error: Putting dashboard failed: InvalidParameterInput: The dashboard body is invalid, there are 4 validation errors:
[
  {
    "dataPath": "/widgets/0",
    "message": "Should be object"
  },
  {
    "dataPath": "/widgets/1",
    "message": "Should be object"
  },
  {
    "dataPath": "/widgets/2",
    "message": "Should be object"
  },
  {
    "dataPath": "/widgets/3",
    "message": "Should be object"
  }
]
    status code: 400, request id: 706ac87c-a796-11e9-8983-65d87c7656b4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code generates like below,

```tf
{
  "widgets": [
    [ // <--- It seems to be wrong.
      {
        "height": 6,
...
```

widgets has lists in a list. So modify like below,

```tf
jsonencode(
    {
      "widgets" : [ //removed [ 
        for inst in range(length(local.instances)) :
        {
...
            "annotations" : {
              "horizontal" : [
                {
                  "label" : "Untitled annotation",
                  "value" : 1.01
              }]
            }
          }
        }
      ] // and removed ] 
  })
```

Remove nested list.